# How can I alias partial classes generated by Entity Framework Code First From Database?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, partial-classes

I'm learning EF code first from database using [this MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The generated model partial class names always match the database object names. Instead **I'd like to assign an alias to the generated database model objects. How should I go about doing this?**

Specifically the database view named `vwDS_ProductCategories` generates a `public partial class vwDS_ProductCategories` which I'd like to alias as `ProductCategories`. The reason for doing this is that non-programmers will see (and make use of) the types exposed by my generated dll. I'd like the type names to make sense to these users.

Comment: I have answered based on Code first, do you meant Database first?

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly. I'm transitioning from database first to code first. By trying it out I learned that the Table attribute works for my database view as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Table("vwDS_ProductCategories")]
public partial class ProductCategories
{
}
```